# How do I load Models in Child controller class & use in Parent class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to organize my Controllers & models, and moving common code to Parent classes. I've managed to organize my models, but am now stuck on organizing the controllers.

My Parent controller is:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $model;

     public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();

    }

public function getDataByCity(){
    echo(json_encode($this->model->getDataByCity()));
}

}?>
```

My Child Controller is like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Hospital extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('hospital_model'); 
      //how do I load this into the Parent's $model variable?
    }
}
}?>
```

In my Child controller class, how do I load the particular model into the Parent's $model variable?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040864/modify-parent-classs-variable-in-extended-class

:)

Comment: I don't think this solves my issue, since the model is loaded by Codeignitor, and a variable made with that name.

Comment: Try to specify the second parameter to assign your model to a different object name`$this->load->model('hospital_model', 'model'); `

Answer (score 1):

in MY_Controller:

```
...
public function set_model($object)
{
    $this->model = $object;
}
...
```

in Hospital:

```
...
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('hospital_model'); 
  parent::set_model($this->hospital_model);
}
```

...

Comment: I get this error: 
Message: Undefined property: Hospital::$hospital_model

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter to assign your model to a different object name. However, `$model` property should be `public`.

Parent controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $model;

     public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();

    }

public function getDataByCity(){
    echo(json_encode($this->model->getDataByCity()));
}

}
```

Child controller:

```
class Hospital extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('hospital_model', 'model'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I get two errors with this:
 Use of undefined constant model - assumed 'model' &
 The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: model

Comment: Make sure `$model` property is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

in MY_Controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function set_model($object)
    {
        $this->model = $object;
        $this->load->model($this->model);
    }

    public function getDataByCity(){
        echo(json_encode($this->model->getDataByCity()));
    }

}
```

in Hospital:

```
class Hospital extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        parent::set_model('hospital_model'); 
    }
}
```